# Playing video on different devices and having the same look/size

Tags: android, exoplayer, camera-view

I am trying to make an app where users post videos and see the posted videos in a feed ( like facebook). It all works. I am using cameraview for capturing video and Exoplayer for playing it. It works fine but the issue is that if video is posted by a device different than the device playing it then the video is not taking the full width of the screen.I guess it depends on the aspect ration/resolution of the video being posted.

How do I overcome this problem? How do apps like fb and instagram ensure the video is playing in the same area on all devices without cropping/stretching it

Thank you

Comment: why dont you scale the exoplayer to fit your screen width?

Comment: It is set to match parent but I guess it is not taking the full width based on the aspect ratio (as it occupied the full height already)